# Installing electric Dyna-Glo 15000 watt garage heater

Tags: garage, heater

I need help on a installing a garage heater. Here is what the manufacturer said to do. I’m just confused.

[image]

Comment: 1) Hire an electrician.  This project needs some esoteric knowledge that a pro will have but not a DIYer.  For example, does the electric service to your house have the capacity to add this?   2) Read the manual.  Don't use the information from the shopping web site.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to put a giant toaster in your garage instead of something more efficient like a mini-split?

Comment: What's the question? Please revise your post to make it clear what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I am more than a little concerned about this. A 15,000 W heater @ 240V = 62.5 A **continuous**. Which means it actually needs 78.125 A rating ==> 80 A breaker. That is a **lot** of power. But more important than it needing that much power, they should be *telling* you to use an 80A breaker. The fact that they are not doing so is a huge red flag.

In addition, this sounds like it is simply a giant toaster. At that size, a heat pump would be more efficient (they always are) and save a lot of money over time. Or, if you have natural gas available, a 50,000 BTU gas furnace would likely make more sense than resistance electric heat.

While in theory any addition of hardwired loads (or significant expansion of floor space = plug-in loads) should require a *Load Calculation*, most people don't do that most of the time. But for a significant change like this, or on-demand water heating, or electric vehicle charging, a load calculation is critical to make sure your overall service is able to support the planned usage.

Comment: Heat pumps aren't *always* the answer. There are plenty of climates where it's too cold for months at a time for air-source heat pumps to operate efficiently (ground-source may work better there, but gets a lot more expensive to install).

Comment: @nobody Agreed. Heat pumps are also going to be quite a bit more in initial cost. Which is why I also suggested a natural gas furnace, though we don't know if OP has gas available or not.

Answer (score 2):

They did not make this clear in the advertising material, but this is an *extremely* ambitious installation.  Very few houses have enough power to run a heater this large.

It cost $500 but you'll spend that much installing it, as well as that much a year running it.  It will cost about $2.00 an hour to run in most places.

The good news is, the heavy wiring and service upgrades you install for this heater will also work for EV charging, which may result in better offers on your house when you sell it.

### The service upgrade

This is gonna suck.  You need 80A of service for this heater.  The people who built your house most likely did not leave you 80A of spare ampacity in the panel, so it is not ready for the enormous power draw of this heater.

That means you will need to upgrade your service, including meter pan (which will necessitate pulling a permit since the power company will not connect power until they see an approval stamp), and main panel.  This alone could be $2000 or more.

Whether you need a service upgrade, and how large, is decided by a “Load Calculation” which needs to be done based on your house's square footage, kitchen-bathroom circuits, and major appliances.

You may be gathering that all this stuff - permit, service upgrade, etc. - is best the realm of a licensed electrician.  Indeed the instructions *require you* to use a licensed electrician.  (Yellow highlight)

[image]

### Wire to that heater

Any heater requires wires sized for 125% of its ampacity.  That being 78 amps, you need 80A wire.

You may have been misled by seeing 10 AWG wire (red highlight).  That is special high-temp heater wire, that can run higher amps because it's designed to run so hot.  You can't do that.  **The heater requires #4 copper wire to it.** The sales literature says that, and so does the Electrical Code (blue text).

Fortunately, you are allowed to run much cheaper #2 aluminum wire (90A) most of the way - to a subpanel right near the heater.  The subpanel does two things.  First it gives you future expansion options.  Second it serves as a legal, sanely priced "splice" between the #2Al feeder and the #4Cu branch wire.  It will cost more to use actual splices, with the special junction box they would require.

That subpanel will also give you a nice dividend on sales price, since it will let the next owner easily hook up electric vehicle charging.

### Alternatives

I know you were expecting this to a $600, $700 deal tops. And a service upgrade may be way more than you bargained for, to the point where you'd be better off installing a proper forced-air gas furnace (and certainly usage costs would be much lower).  So what can we do to rein in costs?

First, if your Load Calculation reveals that you can power a smaller amount of heaters, I would consider *still doing the sub panel anyway*, and then running smaller heaters off of it, possibly multiple. These can be $150-ish 3000-5000W heaters of that style, or simply an array of inexpensive $40-50 Cadet baseboard heaters. It's still going to make your electric bill explode, though.

You could also consider a variety of gas furnaces for this purposes, including ones that mount high on the wall like this unit, including ones that use propane bottles if you don't want to plumb gas.

You could use a "salamander" propane or kerosene heater on an informal basis.

Comment: Only 75 Cents? "Most people do not know how lucky they are." In Germany, 1 hour would cost 4.5$ using that heater in private houses/garages.

Comment: @xeeka I mis-priced, got my BTUs and KW mixed up.  We pay 12 cents a KWH, a bit more in blue states.  Mind you, those are *imperial* KWH :)

Comment: No product can require you to hire someone. That's standard legalese.

Comment: If, I mean if, OP has a big house with a couple of central air zones and gas heat, there should be roughly 80A spare in the winter.  That would take care of the service side problem.

Comment: @isherwood good point.  Wow, it never occurred to me that the intersection of "NEC requires you to follow instructions" with hyper-conservative instructions written by liability lawyers lands you on Planet Ridiculous.

Comment: @jay613 except those instructions are approved by UL, suggesting UL may have required the language due to the high probability of mis-wiring by novices (or high incidence thereof; I'm sure *many* of these heaters are put in with #10 wire).

Comment: A service upgrade doesn't seem to be a forgone conclusion. Large houses these days (especially ones large enough to have a garage big enough to justify a 15KW heater) often have 400A (CL320) service (although in a climate cold enough to justify electric heat in the garage, much of the service capacity may already be consumed by electric heat in the house).

Answer (score -1):

Contact the manufacturer and get a corrected statement, this appears to be written by somebody that did not understand what they were writing. If they will not provide a written statement return the unit. Check for certification labels such as UL. The #10 wire will not work, it does not have enough current capacity for residential use and would be a fire hazard if connected to a breaker capable of supplying the 62.5A needed.  The #4 recommended is OK in copper but is also dependent on the breaker you chose. The breaker is to protect the wire, not the appliance but it also must supply enough current for the appliance without tripping. The #12 wire size is questionable, if there are several and each is within its proper rating it is ok but it does not tell you that. If you decided to install it pick the proper breaker for your panel with a 65A or greater rating and be sure to use the proper size cable. Remember they can build many heaters but you only have one life. The above is based on the statement that it requires 15,000 watts, the amperage calculation confirms this but if they made a mistake in the wattage ane it is 1,500 watts it is a different scenario but amperage would still depend on the voltage.

Comment: The manual is not as strange as these shopping screen shots.  It says it consumes 62.5 amps and instructs you to hire an electrician.  That's it.  No strange incorrect wiring advice in the manual.   Don't use online marketing as installation instructions!

Comment: I do not know how big your garage is but I can heat my oversized 2 car garage with a 5,000 watt electric heater.